# How to complete an array with missing (consecutive) elements | Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an array of consecutive numbers, but some of them are missing. I also know increment step.

```js
var step = 1;
var data = [1,2,3,6,7,10];

// I'd like to output [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

How do I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment. What have you tried so far? Are you running into any specific problems?

Comment: This is unclear, at best. If data is `[1,3,5]` and step =3, what should it be?

Comment: Maybe I've simplyfied my problem too much.
I create another topic with more detailed question. Please follow this  
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771218/genereate-empty-data-bettwen-the-range-of-a-timestamp-date-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var step = 1;
var data = [1,2,3,6,7,10];

var start = data.shift();
var end = data.pop();
var newData = new Array();
for(i=start;i<=end;i+=step){
newData.push(i);
}

//alert(newData);
```

Comment: Should be <= if you want to keep the last digit.

Comment: This will just build a new list, instead of filling the gaps.

Comment: Thanks @Salketer for your answer. Indeed i need solution more like "filling the gaps" instead "creating new list", but this is a correct answer for that question. I created another question with more details here 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771218/genereate-empty-data-bettwen-the-range-of-a-timestamp-date-javascript)

Comment: There are a lot more complexe ways to do it... But with the required input/output this is by far the simplest. I did not find suitable to display code harder to grasp to someone who couldn't build this one.

Answer (score 0):

Salketer has the correct answer, just thought I'd play around and do it a different method and share it.

The idea is it works with any list and no matter the order. I find the min and the max and just rebuild the list from scratch.

```
var data = [1,2,3,6,7,10];
var minmax = findMinMax(data);
console.log(minmax);
var res = createConsecutiveArray(minmax.min, minmax.max);
console.log(res);

function createConsecutiveArray(min, max){
    var res = [];
    for(var i = min; i <= max; i++){
        res.push(i);
    }
    return res;
}

function findMinMax(arr){
    var res = [];
    var min = max = (arr.length > 0) ? arr[0]: 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var temp = arr[i];
        if(temp > max){
            max = temp;
        }
        if(temp < min){
            min = temp;
        }
    }
    return {min: min, max: max};
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle to go with it: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/vtcpyumg/2/

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to create a **new** array with the first and last integers taken from the original array.

Changing an array in place is harder.

This example uses Array.splice to insert missing elements in the existing array as it loops through it.

The elements of the array passed must be in order and multiples of step, if step is not 1.

```
function fill_ints(array, step){
    var i= 0, 
    min= array[0], 
    max= array[array.length-1], 
    diff= 0;
    while(min+step<max){
        diff= Math.floor((array[++i]- min)/step);
        while(--diff){
            array.splice(i++, 0, (min+= step));
        }
        min= array[i];
    }
    return array;
}
```

**1. fill_ints([1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10, 14, 25], 1)**

returned value: (Array)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]

var data2= [0, 6, 18, 30];

**2. fill_ints(data2, 1)**

returned value: (Array)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 27, 30]

**3. fill_ints(data2, 3)**

returned value: (Array)

[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30]