# Generate empty data between the range of a timestamp date | Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, timestamp

I get some statistic data with timestamps. I want to plot it on the chart. 
Data are increment with fixed step (1sec) but some of them are missing.
I want to fill this gaps with self generated timestamp.

```
// exmaple data form 18:00 to 18:47 (step 60000ms)

var data = [
    [1425056400000, 1123], //18:00
    [1425056460000, 1124], //18:01
    [1425056520000, 1125], //18:02
    [1425056580000, 1126], //18:03
    [1425056640000, 1140], //18:04
    [1425057840000, 2123], //18:24
    [1425057900000, 2133], //18:25
    [1425057960000, 2141], //18:26
    [1425059160000, 5129], //18:46
    [1425059220000, 5129]  //18:47
];


// required result
var dataParsed = [
    [1425056400000, 1123], //18:00
    [1425056460000, 1124], //18:01
    [1425056520000, 1125], //18:02
    [1425056580000, 1126], //18:03
    [1425056640000, 1140], //18:04
    [1425056700000, 0], //18:05
    [1425056760000, 0], //18:06
    [1425056820000, 0], //18:07
    //(...)
    [1425057780000, 0], //18:23
    [1425057840000, 2123], //18:24
    [1425057900000, 2133], //18:25
    [1425057960000, 2141], //18:26
    //(...)
    [1425058800000, 0], //18:40
    //(...)
    [1425059160000, 5129], //18:46
    [1425059220000, 5129]  //18:47
];
```

How can I do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you loop through the original array, check whether the current element is the next one in the sequence. If not, use another loop to generate the missing elements:

```
var dataParsed = [];
var lastTime = data[0][0];
var timeStep = 60000;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var curTime = data[i][0];
    if (curTime > lastTime + timeStep) {
        for (var time = lastTime + timeStep; time < curTime; time += timeStep) {
            dataParse.push([time, 0]);
        }
    }
    dataParse.push(data[i]);
    lastTime = curTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a loop which counts from first timestamp to the last, incremented by 60 seconds. Then populate a new array with current values + missing values like below.

```
var dataParsed = [];
for(var i=data[0][0], j=0; i<=data[data.length-1][0]; i+=60000) {
  if(i == data[j][0]) {
    dataParsed.push(data[j]);
    j++;
  } else {
    dataParsed.push([i, 0]);
  }
}
```